# Listed folder cannot be deleted

Tags: 12.04, command-line, server

I have a server with an app on it which uses themes (mollify) however after looking at the website this morning no CSS was being displayed so I had a look at the themes as my first port of call.

What had happened was the theme 'basic' had disappeared from my listing in FileZilla, so the first thing I did was attempt to re-upload it (server is 775 for this folder 755 for all others), when that failed I went to check my user settings etc.

When I did `ls /path/to/themes/` the two listed themes were 'basic' and 'charcoal' and when I did  `ls -l /path/to/themes/` charcoal, which displays in FileZilla, came back as expected - but basic returned:

```
d????????? ? ? ? ? ? basic
```

This to me looks like there is no owner etc of this file any more, but I have personally changed nothing on this server (The physical server crashed and was fixed at the weekend).

I uploaded a backup of this folder under a new name and pointed the index file at this CSS instead, so that users are not effected, but that doesn't help the issue with this file.

I have tried using `rm -r` and `rm -rf` to delete the folder but it returns that it does not exist. I have also then tried using `mv` to rename / move the files but it obviously just returns that it already exists. I'm not using the root user directly, but my own account with sudo privileges, could this be an issue as to why it will not delete?

**Is there a way that I can delete, or restore, this folder when it appears to have no owner?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: first, do `ls -li` to list all files with their inodes. The inode is the number on the left. Note the inode number of your problem directory. Then: `find . -inum xxx -delete` replacing xxx with the inode number.

Comment: This returns `? d????????? ? ? ? ? ? basic` and _ls cannot access /path/to/theme: No such file or directory_   I don't really want to try '?' as an inode number.

Comment: Have you tried changing ownership and permissions of the parent directory? As in `sudo chown -R yourUser /path/to/themes`?

Comment: I can do anything normally to the 'themes' folder with the exception that if I do anything recursive I will always get a warning that there is no such file or directory for 'basic', and I cannot set the owner of 'basic' directly either, with chown, I get the same warning message.

Comment: From Googling I learned that you may want to unmount the file system and do a `fsck` on it, as these question marks point to an inconsistent (and possibly unstable) file system.

Comment: I wasn't able to unmount the filesystem due to other websites on there but a reboot cleared the issue and the 'basic' theme is now returning with an owner and an inode number, even though this didn't work before. Thanks for the help.